# Should function return print in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing function which prepare data in csv file. I wonder what should it return. I thought that information in string for user will be good idea, but how should I do it?

```
return print('Some info')
```

Or just

```
return 'Some info'
```

And how about exceptions, I mean like above. When exception will end work of function should I return print('Some info') or just 'Some info'?

Comment: go with the 2nd way

Comment: You should never use the first one.

Comment: I'd say `return print` is pretty useless. `print` is a function that returns `None`, which is the same thing as `print(...); return`. If you want to return a string, return a string.

Comment: You do not return print. You can return variables, lists, strings, etc...

Answer (score 4):

No, `return` should return the result from the function, not the value of `print` (which is always `None` anyway).

Usually, a function should not print anything at all. In order to make programs modular and reusable, you want to keep any user interaction in the calling code.

For example,

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fib = some calculation ...
    print(fib)
    return fib

fibonacci(33)
```

This function has the side effect of printing the calculated value. But this means that you cannot calculate the value without also printing it. A common design principle from functional programming is that functions should not have side effects anyway. A better design is

```
def fibonacci(n):
    fib = some calculation ...
    return fib

print(fibonacci(33))
```

Exceptions are for situations where the code cannot perform the requested function. For example, you cannot calculate a negative Fibonacci number:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot calculate negative Fibonacci number')
    fib = some calculation ...
    return fib
```

You could call this on arbitrary user input;

```
while True:
    number = input('Give me a number: ')
    try:
        print('Fibonacci: ', fibonacci(int(number))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Oops, try again; ', e)
```

Notice how the `except` actually handles multiple error scenarios: if the use input isn't a number at all, `int(number)` will also raise a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: Okay, now I understand differences of print and return. So what should I do in my case? Do not return anything, return only in exceptions?

Comment: If the string `'Some info'` is the result from the function, that's what you should return. Exceptions are for when the function cannot return a regular value (division by zero would be a typical example).

Comment: Okay, but when exception will occur and make impossible to my master function to end and I should terminate work of my function. For example I want to prepare data but input data is invalid, should I write "except Exception as e: return e"? I'm very grateful for your help. :)

Comment: You should `raise` an exception. See the last example in the answer.

Comment: If the *only* thing you do with a caught exception is re-raise it, there is no point in catching it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're learning Python for the first time. I recommend reading documentation to understand how I/O and function return statements work:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

If you want to return a string in a function, use `return 'Some Info'`.
For printing something to the console for the user to view, simply use `print('Some Info')`. Combining the two seems pretty useless for your purposes.